# In what order should I tackle Duncan and Schwartz' QFT?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, resource-recommendations, education

I'm on my way to self-learning quantum field theory (after getting some mathematical pre-reqs out of the way!), and have a question about the order in which to go through the books I have.

I have Schwartz' text, and Duncan's as well. I'm just unsure whether to do Duncan first or Schwartz.

I've read that Schwartz is more computationally-focused, so perhaps it's better to do that after getting the more conceptual details via Duncan? But on the other hand, I've heard that Duncan is a bit more rigorous and advanced than Schwartz, so maybe I should be tackling Schwartz first? Or maybe even use them alongside each other?

Comment: In my opinion, the best and fastest way to understand something is to do a calculation. For that reason, I suggest reading Schwartz first and then going through the rigor of QFT through Duncan (or Weinberg which would be my choice). Disclaimer: I have a personal relationship with the Schwartz QFT book which may affect my opinion.

Comment: Interesting. I tend to find I learn better with a bit of context to what I'm trying to do. Which I guess Schwartz would provide anyway, to be fair. Thanks for the response :)

Comment: Don't start with the rigorous and advanced version. Start with a book like Schwartz's that gets to the key concepts quickly and efficiently and shows you how to calculate things.